# WebView display blank white screen

Tags: qt, webview, qml

I've used the Webview to display the webpage within the my QtQuick app. But its showing the blank screen instead of displaying the webpage. Also it gives some warning saying "using qt quick 1 code model instead of qt quick 2".

Comment: Can you give the exact warning messages you obtain, which version of Qt and Qt Creator you use and which platform?

Comment: Warning is "Using Qt Quick 1 code model instead of Qt Quick 2.(M324)"
I'm using Qt Creator 3.0.1 and Qt 5.2.1 and i've imported QtQuick2.0 & QtWebkit 3.0 in my qml file

Comment: Have you looked at this bug report: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11040 ?

Comment: @NikhilPatil the warning isn't harmful,it's related to Qt Designer.How did you provide the url to WebView? It must be `http://example.com` or `http://www.example.com` not `example.com` or `www.example.com`,dont forget the **http://**

Comment: Ya i did use http:// and i even tried using local html file.  Even that didn't work either.

Comment: can you give an illustrative example ?

Comment: `Rectangle {
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    color: "#2b2926"

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        x: 25
        y:25
        width: (parent.width)-70
        height: (parent.height)/3
        //title: qsTr("")
        color: "#1e1c1a"
        border.color: "#828282"
                WebView{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    url: "D:\html\html.html"

                }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

`QWebView::url` for ***relative paths*** must be of the form `file:///path/to/your/file`.Therefore, in your case it'll be `file:///D:/html/html.html`

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue here. If you are on Windows, it looks like [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37043) which which is fixed for Qt 5.3 (release date 29th of April).